# Google App Script Search UI Next and Previous Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

Having an error with Previous function, when last search of previous function. 
Its all working but when im going to the last search of previous button. it shows error. it should return "No Match" too like when you're with the last searched data with next button.

```
    `function next(eventInfo){

     var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
     var row=ss.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();    
     var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();

      var start = Number(eventInfo.parameter.hidden)+1;
    var hidden = app.getElementById("hidden");                  
   var data = ss.getRange(2,1,lastrow,6).getValues();// get the 3 columns of data
       for(nn=start;nn<data.length;++nn){ ;// iterate trough
         if(data[nn].toString().toLowerCase().match(item.toString())==item.toString()&&item!='') {;// if a match is found in one of the 3 fields, break the loop and show results
  f1box.setText(data[nn][2]);         
  f2box.setText(data[nn][3]);   
  f3box.setText(data[nn][4]); 
  f4box.setText(data[nn][5]); 
         app.getElementById("previd").setEnabled(true).setText("Previous");                                                                                                
      app.getElementById("nextid").setEnabled(true).setText("Next");                                                                                                
      app.getElementById("txbid").setEnabled(true).setText("Search");                                                                                            
           ss.getRange(nn+2,2).activate();
            lbl.setText("found from"+data[nn][0]+"-"+data[nn][1]+", click Next").setEnabled(true);
          hidden.setValue(nn.toString())  
          break;}}
  return app;
}


function previous(eventInfo){

 var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
 var row=ss.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();    
 var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();`           

var start = Number(eventInfo.parameter.hidden)-1;
        var hidden = app.getElementById("hidden");                  
       var data = ss.getRange(2,1,lastrow,6).getValues();// get the 3 columns of data
           for(nn=start;nn<data.length;--nn){ ;// iterate trough
             if(data[nn].toString().toLowerCase().match(item.toString())==item.toString()&&item!='') {;// if a match is found in one of the 3 fields, break the loop and show results
      f1box.setText(data[nn][2]);         
      f2box.setText(data[nn][3]);   
      f3box.setText(data[nn][4]); 
      f4box.setText(data[nn][5]); 
             app.getElementById("previd").setEnabled(true).setText("Previous");                                                                                                
          app.getElementById("nextid").setEnabled(true).setText("Next");                                                                                                
          app.getElementById("txbid").setEnabled(true).setText("Search");                                                                                            
               ss.getRange(nn+2,2).activate();
                lbl.setText("found from"+data[nn][0]+"-"+data[nn][1]+", click Next").setEnabled(true);
              hidden.setValue(nn.toString())  
              break;}}
return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  ['getNextSibling()'](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#getnextsibling) and ['getPreviousSibling()'](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#getprevioussibling), those method retrieves the siblings element were the sibling has the same parent and precedes the current element.